# IDEA Intellij : Build/make when intellij focus is lost

Tags: intellij-idea

I remember an option to automatically build the current project when the focus on the idea windows is lost (for example you switch from intellij to your browser to test your webapp), but I can't find it (idea 12.1.6).

Do you know where could I enable this feature ?

Thanks

Comment: Oh! someone emailed me... alt-tab... computer goes chugg chugg chugg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button what your are looking for you can find in the deployment tab. Behaviour can be different based on your runner settings. Visit [IntelliJ IDEA Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/deployment-console.html) for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*IntelliJ* can build automatically, after each change (not just when the focus is lost).

<kbd>See File  **->**  Settings  **->**  Compiler  **->**  Make project automatically</kbd>

Comment: it only works while not running. I need to rebuild just when focus is lost (I'm working with jRebel on a webapp)